# How to predict variables based on multiple samples?

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, training-data

**The problem**

I tried to do some ML models but everytime I had some weird plots and I couldn't understand these scores. I'm relatively new to ML and maybe someone can help me with this data with some example (DecisionTreeClassifier/SVM/RandomForestClassifier/KNN) how to deal with it and interpret.

**The dataset**

I have two datasets:

1. "seq.csv" with frequency of every aminoacid in specific protein:

```
A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,K,L,M,N,P,Q,R,S,T,V,W,Y
17,0,6,14,5,11,12,9,19,18,3,2,4,5,4,6,5,9,2,3
17,0,10,8,5,11,1,10,13,16,5,12,3,5,13,6,12,9,3,6
18,0,6,14,6,11,11,9,19,18,3,2,4,5,4,6,5,8,2,3
16,0,11,8,5,11,1,10,13,17,5,12,3,5,13,7,12,9,3,6
```

2. "secstr.csv" with frequency of every bond of secondary structure in specific protein:

```
H,G,I,B,E,S,T,C,' '
108,12,0,0,0,3,12,0,19
102,3,0,1,14,12,15,0,18
109,9,0,0,0,2,14,0,20
103,3,0,1,12,9,13,0,26
```

**Code example**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.asarray(seq_df)
Y = np.asarray(sec_str_df['H'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, shuffle= True)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape
>>>((67, 20), (33, 20))

##########################

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lineReg = LinearRegression()
lineReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Score: ', lineReg.score(X_test, y_test))
print('Weights: ', lineReg.coef_)

plt.plot(lineReg.predict(X_test))
plt.plot(y_test)
plt.show()
>>>Score:  0.6800436491044164
Weights:  [-0.87378736 -0.13286578 -4.03961593  2.71956276 -1.6088727  -1.655681
 -3.381233    1.89215565  1.47324114  5.08374842  1.97302355 -2.77426402
 -0.92489368 -1.24430955  3.09726346 -0.41345148  0.11391256 -1.95393996
 -0.71682087  0.05350237]

##########################

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 4, 
                             random_state = 0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
>>>DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                       max_depth=4, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                       random_state=0, splitter='best')
```

**The goal**

I'm trying to predict likelihood of occurence specific bond in protein based on aminoacid frequency.

Comment: What is your target variable / are your target variables? Is it what you have in secstr.csv? Do the letters in the first csv have the same meaning as in the second?

Comment: No, they have different meaning. Letters in seq.csv are in some way correlated with letters from secstr.csv. When I have more letters for example 'A', 'M', 'N' in seq.csv maybe they have influence on numbers of letter 'H' in secstr.csv

Comment: Earlier I had something like in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64703484/size-1-array-error-when-preparing-decision-model

Comment: Your data looks more like you are looking for a kind of regression, not a kind of classification, right? So for a NN you should not set an activation function in the output layer. Btw. it should not be necessary to build one model per output column. LinearRegression is most likely too simple, so e.g. try a neural network or a tree based regressor (based on a Random Forest Regressor or a Gradient Boosted Tree Regressor)

Comment: What do you mean saying "So for a NN you should not set an activation function in the output layer"?

Comment: An activation function usually maps the activation of the neuron to a value between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1 (depending on the activaton function), but if you want to do regression, you don't want to have this mapping, so you just don't apply an activation function in the output layer.  But ok I guess sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor does that implicitely.

Comment: For neural networks better idea, for this kind of data, is sklearn.neural_network, tensorflow or keras?
Yesterday I tried on linear and logistic regression, random forest, decision tree and the best accuracy had random forest.

Comment: Here is screenshot of plot for letter 'H' from secstr.csv: https://www.linkpicture.com/q/3_499.jpg

Comment: logistic regression is also a classificaton method, so it probably is not so usefull for this kind of problem. RFs, NN and GradientBoostedTrees (like lightgbm) should be a good choice. If you use Tensorflow, you usually use the keras interface. Keras is integrated in Tensorflow. But I would recommend to start with the sklearn classes. Especially if you don't have a machine with a powerfull GPU, that is supported by CUDA.

Comment: It's much easier to learn/handle...